# Setting permissions of symlinks deployed by a buildroot package

Tags: permissions, symlink, buildroot

Just trying to customize permissions for a set of files deployed after installing a buildroot package. Found the FOO_PERMISSIONS feature, that seems to be the proper way to go:

```
define FOO_PERMISSIONS
/usr/share/foo/ r  775 root wheel -  -  -  -  -
endef
...
ifeq ($(BR2_PACKAGE_FOO),y)
$(eval $(generic-package))
endif
```

The problem happens in FOO_PERMISSIONS when iterating recursively with "r" over /usr/share/foo/. Inside that directory there are some sub-directories with some regular files. But also some symlinks pointing to files inside the embedded target platform that doesn't exist in the build platform. For instance:

```
/usr/share/foo/resources/foo.json -> /usr/share/foo/foo.json
```

It seems makedevs doesn't manage symlinks properly:

```
makedevs: chown failed for /BUILDROOT/output/target/usr/share/foo/resources/foo.json: No such file or directory
```

The file exists:

```
$ ls -l /BUILDROOT/output/target/usr/share/foo/resources/foo.json -> /usr/share/foo/foo.json
```

But problem is, it's a symlink pointing to a file that is missing on the build platform:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/foo/foo.json
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/foo/foo.json': No such file or directory
```

This error can be fixed in different ways. The first approach is touching a dummy file inside the build platform:

```
$ touch /usr/share/foo/foo.json
```

But this is a nasty fix.

A second approach would be setting permissions for every single file and symlink deployed, managing regular files with "f" and symlinks with "l" type.

```
define FOO_PERMISSIONS
/usr/share/foo/path/to/regular/file f  775 root wheel -  -  -  -  -
/usr/share/foo/path/to/symlink l 775 root wheel -  -  -  -  -
....
endef
```

But this is not a reasonable fix for packages deploying hundred of files. In this case, you loose the nice recursive feature.

A third approach would be to create all symlinks inside a script at startup. But again, that not seems to be the most convenient way to fix a issue with symlinks permissions.

What should be the most convenient way to proceed in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to avoid this issue is making all symlinks relative. So, instead of using /usr/share/foo/foo.json, point to ../foo.json. Just for reference in case any of you needs this in the future.